# What does partition do in this function?

Tags: python

I came across this question asking what the function 'foo' would accomplish. However, I couldn't understand what the 'partition' in this function is doing? There is no other information provided. I know about partition from a string manipulation point of view but here it is acting on a list.

```
def foo(nums, k):
    pos = partition(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
    if k > pos+1:
        return foo(nums[pos+1:], k-pos-1)
    elif k < pos+1:
        return foo(nums[:pos], k)
    else:
        return nums[pos]
```

Comment: What other research have you done?  Additionally, please remove the image and paste the formatted code properly.

Comment: Can you please provide info about the modules imported? The only partition I know in the standard library is str.partition, but this is not the case.

Comment: All it will do is raise a `NameError`   because its not defined.

Comment: "partition" can mean to separate into 3 things: [values below, the partition value, values above]. And that seems to be the case here. Partition and return the one that contains k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the definition of `partition`.  However, `foo` is most likely trying to find the `k`-th smallest item in `nums`.

The partition function I have in mind splits the list in half and returns the midpoint.  Depending on `k`, the `foo` function decides whether to use the left or right sub-array, and then adjusts the value of `k` accordingly.

Here's a fleshed out example, including some commented out debugging lines that you can enable.  I have used the implementation of `partition()` from *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et al.

```py
import random

def partition(A, p, r):
  """ This uses 1-based indexing.   """
  #print(f"    partition: {A} {p} {r}")

  x = A[r-1]
  i = p - 1
  for j in range(p, r):
    if A[j-1] <= x:
      i = i + 1
      (A[i-1], A[j-1]) = (A[j-1], A[i-1])
  (A[i], A[r-1]) = (A[r-1], A[i])
  return i + 1
  
def partition2(A, p, r):
  """ Zero-based indexing version """
  return partition(A, p+1, r+1) - 1
  
def foo(nums, k):
  #print(f"    foo: {nums} {k}")
  pos = partition2(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1) 
  #print(f"      pos: {pos}")
  if k > pos + 1:
    return foo(nums[pos+1:], k-pos-1)
  if k < pos + 1:
    return foo(nums[:pos], k)
  else:
    return nums[pos]
  
# generate some random samples
random.seed(0)
for sample in range(5):
    # random value [1, 5]
    k = random.randint(1, 5)
    # list of 5 random values in range [0, 20]
    l = [ random.randint(0, 20) for i in range(6) ]
    # result of foo
    res = foo(l, k)
    # inform
    print(f"For list {l} and k = {k}, we got {res}")
```

Here are the results of running this program:

```
  For list [1, 8, 12, 16, 15, 13] and k = 4, we got 13
  For list [4, 11, 18, 6, 16, 15] and k = 3, we got 11
  For list [4, 3, 19, 8, 17, 19] and k = 3, we got 8
  For list [9, 3, 2, 10, 15, 17] and k = 2, we got 3
  For list [6, 13, 10, 19, 20, 11] and k = 1, we got 6
```

Comment: With all the -1's everywhere the code is quite convoluted but I understand the logic